# Why implement a different regex engine (e.g. PCRE) as a pragma?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, re2

I'm curious about the best practices for using a different regex engine in place of the default Perl one and why the modules I've seen are pragmas and not a more traditional OO/procedural interface. I was wondering why that is.

I've seen a handful modules for replacing the Perl regex engine with PCRE (re::engine::PCRE), TRE (re::engine::TRE), or RE2 (re::engine::RE2) in a given lexical context. I can't find any object oriented modules for creating/compiling regular expressions that use a different back end. I'm curious why someone would choose to implement this functionality as a pragma rather than as a more typical module. It seems like replacing the perl regex engine would be a lot harder (depending on the complexity of the API it exposes) than making an XS script that exposes the API that PCRE, TRE, and RE2 already provide.

Comment: What did the authors of those modules say when you asked them?

Comment: It's because it's more natural in Perl to use `s/re/repl/` for instance than to call some module method. also, you'd have to use `q/re/` instead of regex literals.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl I didn't ask them. I thought it would be rude to ask such a basic question directly to the package maintainers rather than a more general forum.

Comment: [MarpaX::Languages::M4](http://metacpan.org/pod/MarpaX::Languages::M4)  is an example of an OO package that is using another regexp engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm curious about...why the modules I've seen are pragmas and not a more traditional OO/procedural interface.

Probably because the Perl regex API, documented in [`perldoc perlreapi`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreapi.html) and available since 5.9.5, lets you take advantage of Perl's parser, which gives you a lot of cool features with little code.

If you use the API, you:

- don't have to implement your own version of `split` and the substitution operator `s///`
- don't have to write your own code to parse regex modifiers (`msixpn` are passed as flags to your implementation's callback functions)
- can take advantage of optimizations like constant regexes being compiled only once (at compile time) and regexes containing interpolated variables being compiled only when the variables change
- can use `qr` in your programs to quote regular expressions and easily interpolate them into other regexes
- can easily set numbered and named capture variables, e.g. `$1`, `$+{foo}`
- don't force users of your engine to rewrite all of their code to use your API; they can simply add a pragma

There are probably more that I've missed. The point is, you get a lot of free code and free functionality with the API. If you look at the implementation of [`re::engine::PCRE`](https://metacpan.org/source/AVAR/re-engine-PCRE-0.17/PCRE.xs), for example, it's actually fairly short (< 400 lines of XS code).

## Alternatives

If you're just looking for an easier way to implement your own regex engine, check out [`re::engine::Plugin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/re::engine::Plugin), which lets you write your implementation in Perl instead of C/XS. Do note that there is a long list of [caveats](https://metacpan.org/pod/re::engine::Plugin#TODO-CAVEATS), including no support for `split` and `s///`.

Alternatively, instead of implementing a completely custom engine, you can extend the built-in engine by using overloaded constants as described in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Creating-Custom-RE-Engines). This only works in constant regexes; you have to explicitly convert variables before interpolating them into a regex.